# How to make a background image stays in the botton and cover the full height

Tags: html, css, wordpress

How can I make all my pages have the same background feeling as my [homepage](http://healinghands.vtable.us/). For example if you see [this](http://healinghands.vtable.us/board-of-directors/) page you can see the background is out of place. Let me know if you want me to send you the code but pretty much you can see it at these pages. Thanks a lot!

PS: Any other way besides using position fixed?

Comment: Would `background-size: cover;` help, or is that not what you're trying to accomplish? I'm not sure I understand the issue.

Comment: And on a side note... Mike isn't a popular name at all, is it?

Comment: yeah you are right! popular name! so Mike this is what I got. Even I used background position still don't get it to stick in the bottom of the page http://healinghands.vtable.us/board-of-directors/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a different approach... Instead of using 2 different gradients in two different div's (`#hhbg` and `#footer`), just combine the two gradients into one image and apply it as a background to, for example, `body`.  Then use `background-position` to anchor the image to the bottom corner and repeat it horizontally.